# Vectorizing for loop on square matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a big square matrix (refConnect) with approx 500000 elements.
I need to perform this operation:

```
tmp = find(referenceCluster == 67);
for j=1:length(tmp)
    refConnect(tmp(j),tmp)=1;
end
```

I wonder if there is a simple way to vectorise this so I can avoid the for loop which is taking forever.
Thanks for any help.
Cheers

Comment: What is the size of `referenceCluster`? Is it a vector of length `size(refConnect,1)`?

Comment: I think the loop can be replaced by just `refConnect(tmp,tmp)=1;` You can also remove `find` as follows: `tmp = referenceCluster==67; refConnect = bsxfun(@times, tmp, tmp.')`

Comment: @LuisMendo I think you're missing a step in the `bsxfun` example, since your output will be the logical (although double because of `@times` not `@and`) matrix, not the original matrix with some values replaced by 1. Also for other readers: since R2016b these two statements are equivalent: `bsxfun(@times, tmp, tmp')` and `tmp .* tmp'`

Comment: Yes Luis you're absolutely right. Thank you

Comment: @Wolfie You are right. I assumed `refConnect` would be initially undefined, as in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you can't significantly decrease execution time.
Try evaluate the execution time with this test function.

```
function test_spped(N, M)
if nargin < 1
    N = 707;
end
if nargin < 2
    M = 2;
end

refConnectIn = rand(N, N);
referenceCluster = randi(M, N, 1);

refConnectA = refConnectIn;
tic
tmpA = find(referenceCluster == 1);
for j=1:length(tmpA)
    refConnectA(tmpA(j),tmpA) = 1;
end
toc

refConnectB = refConnectIn;
tic
tmpB = referenceCluster == 1;
refConnectB(tmpB, tmpB) = 1;
toc

if isequal(refConnectA, refConnectB)
    disp('Result are equals');
else
    disp('Result are UNEQUALS!');
end
```

With default parameters you get:

```
>> test_speed
Elapsed time is 0.002865 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001575 seconds.
Result are equals
```

Note, the execution time of the vectorized code (B case) can be worse for large M:

```
>> test_speed(707,1000)
Elapsed time is 0.001623 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002219 seconds.
Result are equals
```